# How can I use webdriver to let user choose different browser

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Selenium provide many kinds of browser driver, so I want to let the user choose what kind they want.

But in the programming, we have to use global variable. (I use C#)

I cannot use switch or if/else to let the program know which is user want.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at these:

```
RemoteWebDriver
IJavaScriptExecutor
```

all webdrivers are child class or implements RemoteWebDriver and IJavaScriptExecutor, so your global variable should be like:

```
RemoteWebDriver webDriver;
IJavaScriptExecutor executor;
```

And, you init it using if else:

```
if(ie)   
    webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
else if(firefox)    
    webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

and so on.

```
executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriver;
```

Comment: yes , it work. thanks.But it still has some problem.
I cannot use the driver in other class, why?

Comment: How is your class written? These global variables should be public if you want to use it in other class. Or, are they in the same namespace?